# Cookie authentication issues on page request ASP.NET Core & Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

Using ASP.NET Identity in my web application, I force new users to enable 2fa after registration.
The issue: the **first time** a user registers with 2fa (scans the QR code and enters the code) a 404 is thrown. The **second time** or any number of times after that, the request to server is healthy and they are redirected to the website.

After much digging with middleware and http requests I realised that the **first request had an essential cookie expiring 01/01/1970** but any requests made after the first one on the same page had different cookies (which are accepted). I have absolutely no idea why this is, my cookies are registered in `StartUp.cs` and I haven't this issue anywhere else.

#### Fiddler Analysis

I would just like to add that before the request is sent, the Cookies look like the second request, but they are somehow reset to what you can see below which causes the request to fail.

404 Bad Request, URL ===> /Identity/Account/Prompt2FA (**first time request**)
[image]

302 Found, URL ===> /Identity/Account/Prompt2FA (**second time request**)
[image]

Any help on this is much appreciated, if you require any code to help resolve this, please do let me know. I wanted to avoid having a very lengthy question. Thanks!

#### StartUp.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "/Account/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddAntiforgery(option =>
            {
                option.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
                option.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
            });

            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            containerBuilder.Populate(services);
            this.ApplicationContainer = containerBuilder.Build();
            var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
            return serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your startup.cs look?

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen added as per your request, thanks.

Comment: does your cookie last 2 hours or 30 minutes after the initial failure?

Comment: @MattLuccasPhaureJensen I am unsure of how to answer this, after the 404 failure the `Application` section in chrome dev tools shows nothing. However, after going through the login route again the cookies last 2 hours (the same duration showed for the first request before its somehow amended on the way to the controller)

Comment: Ok, if the 2 hour expiration was ignored for a 30 minute expiration I might have had an idea of what was wrong, but right now I am drawing a blank. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So I realised that in StartUp.cs I set

```
    services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
    {
        // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's stat, default is 30minutes.
        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
    });
```

The purpose for this was so that when an Administrator changed a user information (I built a basic Admin CMS). They would be forced to login again as their session would be invalid.

The problem stated in my question arises when a user verifies their Two factor authentication because it changes a field in the database table which then invalidates the users session